# Perf linux tool : Function name not shown in the symbol column

Tags: performance, c

I am not sure if this is the right forum.

I am trying to benchmark a simple compiled c code but i cannot see it's main and child functions in the perf report. All i see are system functions and hex values. Where can i trace my functions main() and addition()?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int addition(int num1, int num2)
{
 int sum;
 /* Arguments are used here*/
 sum = num1+num2;

 /* Function return type is integer so we are returning
  * an integer value, the sum of the passed numbers.
  */
 return sum;
 }

  int main()
 {
 int var1=32, var2=23;

 /* Calling the function here, the function return type
  * is integer so we need an integer variable to hold the
  * returned value of this function.
  */
 int res = addition(var1, var2);
 printf ("Output: %d", res);

 return 0;
  }
```

I compiled it using `gcc t.c -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -o t`. 
`perf -g report ./t`
`perf record -g`

I cannot see my functions in the symbol column.
[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVieo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your example and on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04; perf version 4.4.128) I can see the function name, but not all of them.

I used the command `perf report` to check the profiling, and [I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8zE6.png).

Many of the line are hex addresses because they correspond to kernel-land function and I'm not a kernel developer. IIRC the perf tools are use to profile or retrieve a lot of information about the kernel behavior, so it's not really well adapted for user-land program.

Why don't you use [gprof](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial)?